# "I have learnt" or "I learnt?"

Tags: present-perfect

Is using the simple past wrong in my  first sentence because I am still on this forum learning and does the third sentence suggest that the life experience isn't finished and the speaker may travel again unlike the fourth sentence?

1. "I learnt a lot on this forum."
2. "I have learnt a lot on this forum."
3. "I have travelled all over the world."
4. "I travelled all over the world."

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Simple past implies that it is over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I learnt a lot on this forum."

> "I have learnt a lot on this forum."

> "I have travelled all over the world."

> "I travelled all over the world."

Your interpretation of the 4 examples are generally right.

In (1), the mere use of the determiner 'this' may not mean you must still be in this forum.  One day, when you are no longer in ELL, in a conversation with friends about favourite past interests and club memberships, ELL may be the topic.  In that situation, this sentence may be used.